# How do I test an specific load balancer instance over HTTPS?

Tags: curl, nginx, https, proxy, dns

I have a collection of Nginx services working as load balancers for a single address, let's say `www.example.com`. I would like to have a test suite that targets each of these machines in isolation, not going through the DNS load balancing, as in going straight to the address.

When I try to do something like that in `curl` I get:

```
 $ curl -H "Host: www.example.com" -v  https://10.10.10.10/                         
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* Connected to 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
* SSL: certificate subject name (www.example.com) does not match target host name '10.10.10.10'
* Closing connection 0
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (www.example.com) does not match target host name '10.10.10.10'
```

I know `10.10.10.10` is not the same name, but I'd like to instruct the tool to believe it is (because I know it is, these are all load balancers serving the same domain).

Is there any way to do that that won't involve dealing with DNS resolution?

Comment: Does host file option work for you?

Comment: Also how about running the test inside a docker container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you're having is because the Host header you are setting is being sent to the server, but is not being used by curl for SSL verification.

You can see this in the curl output, notice the "Connected to 10.10.10.10":

```
 $ curl -H "Host: www.example.com" -v  https://10.10.10.10/                         
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* Connected to 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) port 443 (#0)
```

You are likely looking for the --resolve flag:

> --resolve `<host:port:address>`
>
> Provide a custom address for a specific host and port pair. Using this, you can make the curl requests(s) use a specified address and prevent the otherwise normally resolved address to be used. Consider it a sort of /etc/hosts alternative provided on the command line.
>
> See: [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve)

With this in mind, you probably want to try:

`curl -v --resolve www.example.com:443:10.10.10.10 https://www.example.com`

Which should make it evident in the output that curl is now using the hostname, thus, allowing the validation of the certificate subject name:

```
$ curl -v --resolve www.example.com:443:10.10.10.10 https://www.example.com
* Added www.example.com:443:10.10.10.10 to DNS cache
* About to connect() to www.example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* Connected to www.example.com (10.10.10.10) port 443 (#0)
```